# org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Cannot use a complex object as a key value

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, groovy, spring-data

am working with spring boot and mongoDB. have written the repository for my model and have written my own logic to increment id by using mongo inc.  while doing

> gradle test

the tests are failing with the following exception.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Cannot use a complex object as a key value.
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeMapInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:669)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.createMap(MappingMongoConverter.java:585)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:471)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:430)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:418)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:322)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:418)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:392)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:356)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:79)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.toDbObject(MongoTemplate.java:853)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:1014)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:963)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:80)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.save(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository$save.call(Unknown Source)
at com.auth.mongo.impl.ApplicationRepositoryImpl.save(ApplicationRepositoryImpl.groovy:26)
at com.auth.repository.ApplicationRepository$save$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
```

can any one suggest me what am doing wrong

**EDIT:**
FOR Example: Application Class is the domain

```
class Application implements Serializable {

String id
APIKey apiKey
Map actions = [:]

Application() {
}

Application(APIKey apiKey) {
    this.apiKey = apiKey
    List customerActionsList = [] // added some actions
    actions.put(Role.User, customerActionsList)
}
```

APIKey:

```
String apiKey
String application
DateTime whenCreated
boolean active

APIKey() {
}

APIKey(String application, DateTime whenCreated, boolean active) {
    this.apiKey = generateAPIKey(application)
    this.application = application
    this.whenCreated = whenCreated
    this.active = active
}
```

repository class is as follows:

```
@Component 
class ApplicationRepositoryImpl implements ApplicationRepository {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationRepositoryImpl.class)

@Autowired
ApplicationRepositoryMongo applicationRepositoryMongo

@Autowired
SequenceRepository sequenceRepository

@Override
Serializable save(Application application) {
    application.id = application.id?:sequenceRepository.getNextSequenceId(Application.simpleName).sequence
    return applicationRepositoryMongo.save(application).id
}

@Override
Application find(String id) {
    return applicationRepositoryMongo.findOne(id)
}
```

I am incrementing the id of Application class as follows

```
public SequenceId getNextSequenceId(String type) {
    //get sequence type
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(type))
    //increase sequence id by
    Update update = new Update()
    update.inc('sequence', 1)
    //return new increased i
    FindAndModifyOptions options = new FindAndModifyOptions()
    options.returnNew(true)
    //this is the magic happened
    SequenceId seqId = mongoOperation.findAndModify(query, update, options, SequenceId.class)
    return seqId
}
```

While saving the domain object getting the above exception. I have done all mongo configuration. the configuration is working for other domains.

Comment: Exception seems quite clear (for You - nobody can help You without code)

Comment: Hey @Jacek Cz I have updated my question with code. please take a look and help now

Answer (score 0):

There's an open Improvement in Spring [Don't require Converters for Complex classes that are used as Ids](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-485). Currently Spring decided to not support it.

> decided not to support it at all